# Ignorant Chemistry question

Tags: math-operators, chemistry, overset

I would like a double harpoon arrow representing a reversible reaction having a forward operator k1 above the harpoon, and a reverse operator k-1 below the harpoon.

But `\overset{k_1}\underset{k_-1}{\rightleftharpoons}` returns an invalid equation.

How do I do this?

Comment: You're missing `{}`'s but wasn't it better to have a look at the mhchem or chemmacros packages? (the latter is probably not spelled like that)

Comment: Trying to do this in word so no idea what mhchem or chemacros is

Comment: Both are packages, look them up online

Answer (score 6):

[image]

With the help of `chemfig`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}

\begin{document}
\schemestart
A \arrow{<=>[$k_1$][$k_{-1}$]} B
\schemestop
\end{document}
```

or `mhchem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}

\begin{document}
\ce{A <=>[{$k_1$}][{$k_{-1}$}] B}
\end{document}
```

or `chemformula`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemformula}

\begin{document}
\ch{A <=>[ $k_1$ ][ $k_{-1}$ ] B}
\end{document}
```

or with `xymtex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xymtexpdf}

\begin{document}
{\reactarrowsep=2pt
A \reacteqarrow{0pt}{1cm}{$k_1$}{$k_{-1}$} B}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Although `chemarr` is a slightly outdated package because it dates back to 2016/05/16, it performs the same functions as indicated by the very good user **@leandriis**.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{chemarr}
\begin{document}
\[\mathrm{CO}_2\xrightleftharpoons[k_{-1}]{k_1}\mathrm{C}+\mathrm{O}_2\]
\end{document}
```